# many core files( e.g core.1678 etc ),how to find where the exactly error is. By using gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

`core.1678`,`core.1689`, how can i resolve this problem using `gdb.i` have tried gdb bt option but it is not resolving the error.

```
gdb -bt core.1678
(gdb) core
No core file now.
(gdb) n
The program is not being run.
(gdb) r
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb) core.1678
/home/deepak/deepak/mss/.1678: No such file or directory.
(gdb) /home/deepak/deepak/mss/core.1678
```

help me out

Comment: gdb <executable file> <core file>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> many core files( e.g core.1678 etc )...

This indicates that your same program or different programs in that particular directory  is continuously crashing. When your machine is configured to generate dump file, it creates the file in the form of **core.(PID)**.  You may refer many useful article regarding the core dump file. You may refer my blog as well which explains about core dump analysis and its internal.

http://mantoshopensource.blogspot.sg/2011/02/core-dump-analysis-part-ii.html

The basic command to load and analyze the core dump file using GDB is as follows:

```
mantosh@ubuntu:~$ gdb
// This is how you would open the core dump file.
(gdb) core core.23515
(no debugging symbols found)
Core was generated by `./otest LinuxWorldRocks 10'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
[New process 23515]
==> Signal 11(SIGSEGV) was the reason for this core-dump file
==> pid of a program is 23515
#0 0x080485f8 in ?? ()

// Load the debug symbol of your program(build with -g option)
(gdb) symbol ./otest
Reading symbols from /home/mantosh/Desktop/otest...done.

// Now you can execute any normal command which you perform while debugging(except breakpoints).
(gdb) bt
#0 0x080485f8 in printf_info (info=0x8ec5008 "LinuxWorld") at test.c:58
#1 0x080485c2 in my_memcpy (dest=0x8ec5012 "", source=0xbfb9c6fe "Rocks",
length=10) at test.c:47
#2 0x0804855d in main (argc=3, argv=0xbfb9b3f4) at test.c:33
```

**EDIT**

cored-ump file is the snapshot of that particular program at the time of exception/segmentation fault. So once you load core-dump in GDB you would only be able to execute the command to read
the memory information. You can not use the debugging commands like breakpoints, continue, run ...etc..........